# webpagetest batch test from different locations?

Tags: webpagetest

In webpagetest, is it possible to perform a batch of test from different locations? I cannot find detailed information about their "bulk test" feature in the webpage. I try to ask on their forum, but the post is hidden after sometime.

Thanks